# The device bluetooth ralink rt3290 is not recognized on my laptop hp pavilion g4-2240br

Tags: 13.04, bluetooth, hp-pavilion, ralink

OS: Ubuntu 13.04.

Laptop: hp pavilion g4-2240br.

Device Bluetooth: Ralink rt3290.

The device Bluetooth ralink rt3290 is not recognized on my laptop hp pavilion g4-2240br ,the wireless device works perfectly but no Bluetooth device. I've ran the command lsusb and rfkill list all and saw that theoretically the drivers are installed correctly but the Bluetooth device does not work:

```
HP-Pavilion-g4-Notebook-PC: ~ $ lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp.. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp.. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c8: 0348 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink)
HP-Pavilion-g4-Notebook-PC: ~ $ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 0):

The default wifi drivers provided on Ubuntu 13.04 don't work very well and there are no drivers currently available for the bluetooth on the rt3290 chip on 13.04 due to modifications in kernel and unavailability of an updated driver.

However, you can switch back to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Long Term Support till 2017). The proprietary drivers perform really well on 12.04, here's a link to my blog : [Setting Up Wifi and Bluetooth on 12.04 LTS](http://lifeindwarka.blogspot.in/2013/08/setting-up-hp-pavilion-g6-2313ax-on.html)

It explains all the steps required to successfully setup bluetooth and wifi on 12.04 LTS. Feel free to leave any comments or questions :-)